# Zend Optimizer is it work a try?

Tags: php, php-5.3, zend-optimizer

I have a server:

```
Intel Processor: Intel® Xeon® X3450, 4x2x2.66 GHz
RAM memory:   8GB ECC DDRIII
```

The per day visitors:

```
100k unique
400k clicks
```

Basically, 20 domains run from a single script. I do quite often update the script. Daily. I was wondering whether Zend Optimizer is a good option to optimize script perfomance. (even though, I don't feel any discomfort at the moment)

My two main concerns are:

1. Will it actually increase page
   loading time/decrease server RAM/CPU
   load? If so, by how much (%)?
2. Isthere a comfortable way, using OS
   X,
       to keep original files on Local disk
       and every time you press save, for
       the program to automatically encode
       files and upload them to the server?
       (I am using Panic's Coda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your first point. No, Zend Optimizer was only really relevant with php4. Since PHP5, the internal engine/ has been improved such that the optimizer is redundant.
What you should look at using if you are not already is APC [1], there is lots of stuff on here and google about it but in short, it caches your code so PHP doesn't have to compile it every time the page is run. (and it makes a MASSIVE difference to code execution speed)

You should also look at running some form of profiler such as XHprof [2] or xdebug[3] on the code so you can see where the bottlenecks are.

You might also want to think about using a different web server such as nginx/lighttpd/apache or fine tuning its configuration

For you second question about Coda - ask it as another question on here or programmers.stackoverflow

[1] http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php
[2] http://mirror.facebook.net/facebook/xhprof/doc.html
[3] http://www.xdebug.org/

Comment: Is APC similar, identical to memcache(d)?

Comment: APC can fulfil 2 roles, one of them as a code cache for use by the Zend Engine, and the other is as a cache (aka user cache) for storing and accessing variables inside scripts in the same way as memcached does. When you install APC it gives you both systems but you can pick and choose about which you use. APC's user cache is only accessible from the local machine unlike Memcache which is network accessible.

Comment: I see. So I still need to use memcache and APC.

Comment: pretty much yes! There aren't many good reasons not to use APC in production.